# MySQL query: one table, two levels of SELECT. Is there a better way?

Tags: mysql, select

I've got a table called "double_select" that looks like this:

```
itemID | orderID | status
------   -------   ------
   1        1       ready
   2        1       ready
   3        1      waiting
   4        2      complete
   5        3       ready
  ...      ...       ...
```

And with one SQL command I want to retrieve:

- all items with status "ready"
- all other items for any orderID returned above

So in the above table snippet, I'd like to return itemID's 1, 2, 3 & 5.

I can do this with this statement:

```
SELECT `a`.* FROM `double_select` AS `a`, `double_select` AS `b` WHERE `a`.`status` = "ready" OR (`a`.`status` != "ready" AND `b`.`orderID` = `a`.`orderID` AND `b`.`status` = "ready") GROUP BY `a`.`itemID`;
```

But it doesn't seem very clean. Is there a better way of doing this?

Table details are below, thanks a lot,

James

```
CREATE TABLE `double_select` (`itemID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,`orderID` int(11) default NULL,  `status` varchar(128) default NULL,  PRIMARY KEY  (`itemID`),  KEY `Status` (`status`)) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
insert  into `double_select`(`itemID`,`orderID`,`status`) values (1,1,'ready'),(2,1,'waiting'),(3,1,'waiting'),(4,2,'complete'),(5,2,'ready'),(6,3,'ready'),(7,3,'ready'),(8,4,'complete'),(9,5,'failed'),(10,6,'complete');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subquery example:

```
select * 
from double_select
where orderID in 
    (select orderID 
     from double_select 
     where `status` = 'ready')
```

Comment: A good query planner will see this as equivalent to the JOIN syntax in my answer and optimise accordingly (I've not used mySQL for a while, but I'm pretty sure it is intelligent enough). Be careful if stuck using some ancient or otherwise bad database system though as you might find it runs the sub-select once for every row in double_select or may end up table scanning the outer select even if it only runs the nested select once, either which would be very inefficient.

Comment: Brilliant, it's clearly readable and works efficiently. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is fine. You could also do it with a subquery, but you still would query the same table twice.

Edit: Maybe you can change it to something like this:

```
SELECT a.* FROM double_select AS a LEFT JOIN double_select AS b ON a.OrderId = b.OrderId
WHERE a.status = ready or b.status = ready
GROUP BY a.ItemId;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** *I initially missed the obvious requirement that we should allow for multiple items in the ready state per order. The `LEFT OUTER` join added in this edit along with a check to exclude rows where it matches anything (so only the ready item with the lowest itemID is considered) deal with this - but at this point the sub-query method is* far *clearer, and if your query planner is bright enough (which most should be these days) probably more efficient too. I've left this (corrected) answer in place for reference.*

Your two conditions `or`ed in the `where` clause may well cause the query planner not to use any index you may have on the `status` column. I would use the newer (SQL92) `JOIN` syntax to make it explicit that you want "things from A that are ready" as your main limiting filter like so:

```
SELECT assoc_with_ready.field1, assoc_with_ready.field2
FROM   double_select AS ready_items
LEFT OUTER JOIN
       double_select AS duplicate_ready_itmes
       ON     duplicate_ready_itmes.orderID = ready_items.orderID 
       AND    duplicate_ready_itmes.status = 'ready'
       AND    duplicate_ready_itmes.itemID < ready_items.itemID
INNER JOIN
       double_select AS assoc_with_ready
       ON     assoc_with_ready.orderID = ready_items.orderID 
WHERE  ready_items.status = 'ready'
AND    duplicate_ready_itmes.itemID IS NULL
```

Note: there is no need to check for `status<>'ready'`, as the query will not return duplicate rows (some from A and some from B) in queries like this (thoughs without a `UNION` or `CROSS JOIN`), unless you want all rows associated with ready items but not the rows marked as ready themselves. If I'm reading your question wrong and you *don't* want the rows marked as ready, add `AND assoc_with_ready <> 'ready'` to the `ON` clause of the `JOIN`.

Two points of coding style that tend to make things easier to debug later (or easier to avoid bugs in the first place): use descriptive names for table aliases (though you may have just used A and B as examples for brevity), and try to avoid selecting `*` (give explicit field names instead where possible).

I'm not sure that your `GROUP BY` clause is trying to do, as you have not applied any aggregates at all. With your example statement I would expected errors regarding a.orderid and a.status (selected by the *) not being in the `group by` clause or an aggregate function. Even with all the selected items in aggregate functions the grouping will have no effect as ItemID is a unique column so you'll end up with one row per itemID with or without the grouping. If you just want a list of all the rows that are ready or associated with one that is ready then the query above will do that without any grouping.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm afraid I couldn't get this to work though. The JOIN method appends the joined data in new columns on the same row and not as distinct new rows. Perhaps I'm not using the newer SQL92 join method though?

BTW: the GROUP BY was to prevent the multiple results I was receiving for each itemID (which is why I presumed this could be done better).

Comment: I made a mistake in my SQL, joining on the ItemID columns not the orderID ones. I've corrected the SQL in my answer. You will probably want an index on the OrderID column BTW, for either this or the sub-query based version (with a good query planner the two techniques should be equivalent, and both will benefit from an index the same).

Comment: Your query needs too `GROUP BY assoc_with_ready.itemID` to prevent multiple identical rows shown.

Comment: @ypercube: ah, heck, I missed the possibility that there might be (indeed there are likely to be) more than one row with `status='ready'` for any given orderID. Though simply grouping by OrderID or ItemID will not have the desired effect. I'll edit again...

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do this. Just adding more options:

```
SELECT * 
FROM double_select AS d
WHERE EXISTS  
    ( SELECT * 
      FROM double_select AS dd
      WHERE dd.status = 'ready' 
        AND dd.orderID = d.orderID 
    )

SELECT d.* 
FROM double_select AS d
  JOIN
    ( SELECT DISTINCT orderID 
      FROM double_select 
      WHERE status = 'ready'
    ) AS ds
    ON ds.orderID = d.orderID  

SELECT a.*
FROM double_select AS a 
  JOIN double_select AS b
    ON a.orderId = b.orderId
WHERE b.status = 'ready'
GROUP BY a.itemId
```